# Qwebview with threading in python qt

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, python-multithreading, qwebview

I want to run multiple QWebview using multi-threading for scrape data. But have no idea about how to implement thread using qwebview. Here I have write some code:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
from PyQt4.QtNetwork import *
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from lxml import etree,html
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt
import sys



class Form(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.browser =  QWebView()
        self.browser.connect(self.browser,SIGNAL('loadFinished(bool)'),self.loadFinished)
        #vbox.addWidget(self.browser)
        self.browser.load(QtCore.QUrl("http://www.google.com"))
        self.browser_tabs   = QTabWidget()          
        self.browser_tabs.setTabPosition(QTabWidget.South)
        b1_tab  = QWidget() 
        d = QHBoxLayout()
        d.addWidget(self.browser)
        b1_tab.setLayout(d)
        self.browser_tabs.addTab(b1_tab,"browser0")
        vbox.addWidget(self.browser_tabs)

        self.setLayout(vbox)
    def loadFinished(self,ok):
        print ok


def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Form()
    ex.show()
    ex.setGeometry(150, 100, 1024, 770)

    #ex.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You can use tab widget for open multiple browser.

Answer (score 0):

Define a new function for your Form class. And use thread.start_new_thread(function_name, arguments()).

```
import thread

class Form(QWidget):
...
    def addNewTab(self, newUrl, tabIndex):
        new_browser = QWebView()
        new_browser.connect(self.browser,SIGNAL('loadFinished(bool)'),self.loadFinished)
        new_browser.load(QtCore.QUrl(newUrl))
        new_tab = QWidget()
        d = QHBoxLayout()
        d.addWidget(new_browser)
        new_tab.setLayout(d)
        self.browser_tabs.addTab(new_tab, "browser" + str(tabIndex))

        # Do your scraping here

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Form()
    ex.show()
    ex.setGeometry(150, 100, 1024, 770)

    thread.start_newThread(ex.addNewTab, (someUrl1, 1))
    thread.start_newThread(ex.addNewTab, (someUrl2, 2))
    thread.start_newThread(ex.addNewTab, (someUrl3, 3))

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: thank for your answer. If it is possible, can you write full code?

Comment: I think I wrote enough. I don't know much about data scraping so I have left that part unwritten. I'm sorry I can't help you there.

Comment: @okorkut. I'm afraid your code cannot possibly work. All gui operations **must** happen in the main thread.

Comment: You are right. What if we separate the scraping function from addNewTab function. We can create our tabs in the main thread and call scrapeData function within the new threads.

Comment: @okorkut. You could, but the scraping would have to be done differently. The advantage of using a browser is that it loads all the resources, runs javascript code, etc, so it renders the complete page. Anyway, to scrape multiple pages in parallel, I think the correct approach is to use a separate *process* for each page, not a separate *thread*.